# Angular Material Datepicker pop up out of place

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material version 1.1.4 with Angular version 1.5.9, when I add md-datepicker on my page the datepicker's popup is opening out of position.

[image: Out of Position Pop up]

Comment: can you please check if your application CSS overriding angular material CSS somehow ?

Comment: I do not have any other css except angular-material.css and angular-material-icons.css

Comment: its difficult to analyse; plz post HTML and controller code may be

Comment: @TanveerRafique There is no problem with the use of md-datepicker with AngularJS 1.5.9 and Angular-Material 1.1.4. Look a [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXohk7sFSd4qHXz3FGgW?p=preview) it's working fine. So you need to provide us some of your code because it's not due to the versions you are using.